# keyboard covering part of edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

When I click on the EditText, the keyboard pops out and covers a part of the EditText. I want the EditText to be **completely visible**.

I have tried adjustPan and adjustResize and they are not working. I want to do this in a fragment.

This is how it looks right now

[image: This is how it looks right now]

This is how I want it to be

[image: This is how i want it to be]

**Update:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#EAEAEA"
    android:clickable="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/messages"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/close_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/close" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/message_area"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/edit_control"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageSmsProfile"
        android:background="#EAEAEA"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:overScrollHeader="#EAEAEA" >
    </ListView>

    <com.monqi.kid.custom.CustomRoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageSmsProfile"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_50dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle_shape"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:left_bottom_corner_radius="10dip"
        app:left_top_corner_radius="10dip"
        app:right_bottom_corner_radius="10dip"
        app:right_top_corner_radius="10dip" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/edit_control"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_chat_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_chat_send"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button_chat_send"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_drawable"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textImeMultiLine"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_chat_send"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/send_button"
            android:text="@string/send"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use tpA's answer and also put your view inside ScrollView.

Comment: Please try to put your layout in ScrollView

Comment: can you put your xml

Comment: @AbleAlias that does not help

Comment: @Umesh any solution for this. The year is 2020 and we are still stuck at this.

Answer (score 1):

use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"`

Comment: Its is a fragment hence cannot set windowsoftinputMode. I have tried setting these flags for the activity that owns the fragment. Does not work

Comment: @EminenT using both the adjust*** attribute value is not the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

Add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustResize" in AndroidManifest and use a scrollView contains your rootView.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when i was stuck in same kind of scenario where i have added the following line of code in my onCreate(),Hope this helps

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Comment: Its a fragment hence cannot set windowsoftinputMode. I have tried setting these flags for the activity that owns the fragment. Does not work

Comment: I think all fragments of one Activity have the same behaviour as their parent Activity, but if you need different keyboard behaviour for different Fragments, you could dynamically change this property from your Fragment code like this:                                                                                                     getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.softInputMode.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

Answer (score 0):

**try this xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp">
</ListView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/form"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/chatText"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonSend" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send"
        android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/chatText"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```